# Use of logical not operator (twice) on right hand side of expression with pointer variable

Tags: c, pointers, logical-operators

Why would anyone type `variable = !!ptr` as an expression? Looks like a bug or unintentional defect to me.  The result should be just `ptr`, but one must wonder the original intent.  Thoughts?

Comment: It's a bug, but only in the documentation.  In production code, an obscure line like that should be accompanied by a comment along the lines of "Normalize pointer non-NULL status to bool", or something.

Answer (score 3):

The `!` operator results in a value of 0 if its operand is equal to 0, or 1 otherwise.

If `ptr` is 0 (or NULL if it's a pointer), then `!ptr` will evaluate to 1, and `!!ptr` will evaluate to 0.  If `ptr` is not 0 (or not NULL), then `!ptr` will evaluate to 0 and `!!ptr` will evaluate to 1.

So the end result of `!!ptr` is that the value of `ptr` is normalized to a boolean value, i.e. 0 will remain 0 and non-zero will be converted to 1.

Comment: Right, but it makes no sense to do this.  Its likely a typo.  It was found outside of a condition in an ordinary expression like variable = !!parg;   Just seems odd.

Comment: @ericshufro It is not a condition. It is assigning `variable` with `1` if the pointer is non-NULL, or `0` otherwise. Pretty legit thing to do depending on the context. This is equivalent to `variable = ( ptr != NULL );`

Comment: Understood. thanks for clarifying.

Comment: so why do we need !! vs just using a single !  to get the 0/1 normalization?

Comment: What is the type of `variable`?

Comment: @ericshufro A single `!` inverts the boolean equivalence.  Using `!` twice keeps it the same.

Comment: @ericshufro Presumably the meaning of `variable` is "status of `ptr`".  If you use `variable = !pointer`, then `variable` means "pointer is bad", that is, `variable` is true if `ptr` is NULL, and `variable` is false if `ptr` is non-NULL.  If you use `variable = !!pointer` , on the other hand, then the sense of `variable` is "pointer is good".

Answer (score 0):

For all scalar types, `!x` is equivalent to `x == 0` and `!!x` is equivalent to `x != 0`. `!!x` is hence an idiom to normalize `x` as a boolean.

If the type of `variable` is `bool`, `variable = !!ptr` is indeed equivalent to `variable = ptr` and will generate the same code.

Which one is more readable is debatable: implicit conversion to `bool` is somewhat confusing and error prone because `variable = ptr` would mean something totally different if `variable` has a different integer type, whereas `!!ptr` is safe and explicit, once you master the idiom.

Comment: The best and most readable option might be `variable = (bool)ptr;`. Less confusing than `!!`.

Comment: @Lundin: that's correct, as long as `bool` is defined as `_Bool` (eg: by including `<stdbool.h>`), not some legacy emulation using an integer type... In other words, `variable = (bool)ptr` is not portable to pre-C99 targets.